# Python: Read .txt file and merge based on shared column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two .txt files with different data/information which has about 20 columns each with a different headers. I am trying to merge the two text files based upon a shared column. I keep receiving errors because I believe python is not understanding where the header is.

Thank you so much!

```
# Reading the csv files
df = pd.read_csv('file1.txt', sep='delimiter')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.txt', sep='delimiter')

output1 = pd.merge(df1, df2,
                   on='KeyNumber',
                   how='inner')

Error: KeyError: 'KeyName'
```

Comment: show us result of `df.reset_index().columns` and df2 as well

Comment: @eshirvana when I print that, (['index', 'date_of_extract\torganisation_number\tregistered_charity_number\tlinked_charity_number\tclassification_code\tclassification_type\tclassification_description'], dtype='object')

Answer (score 0):

put it here as it won't fit in comment section.

so seems like your delimiter is `\` , so you should pass `delimiter` parameter when you read your files:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file1.txt', delimiter ='\')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.txt', delimiter ='\')
```

and also there is no column called `KeyNumber` in your df